# Drilling *into* objects with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, hierarchy

I am a rookie programmer with limited experience with d3.  I am hoping to create an interactive hierarchical layout where the user can drill *into* each object and open up nested objects within the 'box' of the original object.  For example, clicking on a certain rectangle would reveal the children of that parent rectangle, while leaving the un-clicked parent rectangles alone (or ultimately fading them out temporarily, etc.).  The idea would be to follow a similar logic to the [zoomable icicle example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/1005873/), but to only initially show the highest-level of the hieararchy on load and then open lower levels when clicking on the parent.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JxMSW/1/) is what I have so far, where clicking on rectangle "One" should reveal additional rectangles (e.g., "One_A" and "One_B") within the box for rectangle "One" (right now, clicking just turns the rectangle purple).  Apologies in advance if I'm missing something basic.  I imagine there may be easier ways to do this (maybe jquery) than with d3, but I am hoping to eventually incorporate nested data-driven elements further down the hierarchy, so that is why I am trying to do it all with d3.  Should I be adding SVG groups within each of the highest-level rectangles and 'activating' the sub-group with an event listener?  Or using the hierarchical layout approach?  Or some combination of the two?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code so far:

```
//Make the overall SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                 .attr("width", 1200) 
                                 .attr("height", 1200); 

//Make group for the highest level of rectangles                                     
var rectsGroup = svgContainer.append("g");

//Data for the highest level of rectangles      
var rectData = [
{ "x": 10, "y": 10, "width": 0, "height": 0, "fill": "blue", "label": "One" },
{ "x": 310, "y": 10, "width": 0, "height": 0, "fill": "red", "label": "Two" },
{ "x": 10, "y": 310, "width": 0, "height": 0, "fill": "green", "label": "Three" },
{ "x": 310, "y": 310, "width": 0, "height": 0, "fill": "orange", "label": "Four" }];

//Data for the second-highest level of rectangles within one rectangle?
var rectOneData = [
{ "x": 10, "y": 10, "width": 150, "height": 150, "fill": "purple", "label": "One_A" }];

//Creating the 4 highest-level rectangles in the group within the main SVG container

var rects = rectsGroup.selectAll("rect")
                      .data(rectData)
                       .enter()
                       .append("rect");

var rectOne = rectsGroup.select('[id="One"]')
                        .append("g");

//Add the attributes
var rectAttributes = rects
                   .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x - 155; })
                   .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y - 155; })
                   .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width; })
                   .attr("height", function (d) { return d.height; })
                   .style("fill", function (d) { return d.fill; })
                    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.label; })
                   .on("mouseover", function() {
                        console.log(this);
                        console.log(d3.select.this);

d3.select(this).transition().style("fill", "yellow");
                        })
                    .on("mouseout", function() {
                        console.log(this);
                        console.log(d3.select.this);

d3.select(this).transition().style("fill", function (d) { return d.fill; });
                        })
                   .transition()
                   .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x ; })
                   .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y ; })
                    .attr("width",300)
                    .attr("height",300)
                    .duration(1500)
                    .delay(10); 

//Acting on a particular SVG object on click...
var rectReceivingAttributes = d3.select('[id="One"]')
                    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.label; })
                        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x ; })
                        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y ;})
                        .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width ; })
                        .attr("height", function (d) { return d.height ; })
                    .on("click", function() {
                        rectsGroup.select('[id="One"]').transition().style("fill", "purple")});


var text = rectsGroup.selectAll("text")
                   .data(rectData)
                    .enter()
                    .append("text");

var textLabels = text
             .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x + 155; })
             .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y + 155; })
             .text( function (d) { return d.label;})
             .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
            .attr("font-size", "20px")
             .attr("fill", "black")
             .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
             .attr("opacity", 0)
             .transition()
             .attr("opacity", 100)
             .duration(3000)
             .delay(1000);
```

Comment: It sounds like you would want to add only the highest-level objects to start with and load additional data as it is required, i.e. when the user clicks on something.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @LarsKotthoff.  I've gotten a little further (http://jsfiddle.net/JxMSW/2/).  Now, a second level ("One_A" and "One_B") appears within rectangle "One" on click, but I've only been able to do this using transitions.  I think I am realizing that my real question is: How would you convert the levels in hierarchical data into *depth* in a graphic, so that clicking on one level would reveal the next level in the hierarchy?  I sort of have the idea working in the fiddle above, but there must be a better way than hard coding everything.  Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The basic idea is that your main rendering function would be passed something like a container and then layout the current level within that. This way it doesn't matter whether you're doing this at the top level or further down.